# how to update large number of records as a batch of n number of records

Tags: database, oracle

suppose I have 100000 records in A table and 1000 records in B table. both have primary/foreign key relationship. now i want to update a column value for first 100 records in table A with column value from table B first record. similary i want to update all the 100000 records in table A as a batch 100 records for 1000 times with values from table B.

no. of records updated per batch is 100 i.e. 100000/1000=100

Comment: What is the *first N records*? RDBMS table is a set, it has no order.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have `table_a` with 20 rows with a unique `id` column and you want to update the `value` column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (id, value) AS
SELECT LEVEL, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(8,0)) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20;
```

And `table_b` with 5 rows containing the values you want to update from:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_b (id, value) AS
SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Then, you can use a correlated `UPDATE` statement:

```sql
UPDATE table_a a
SET value = (SELECT value
             FROM   table_b b
             WHERE  CEIL(a.id*5/20) = b.id);
```

or a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_a a
USING table_b b
ON (CEIL(a.id*5/20) = b.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET value = b.value;
```

Both statements result in:

> | ID | VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 |
> | 2 | 1 |
> | 3 | 1 |
> | 4 | 1 |
> | 5 | 2 |
> | 6 | 2 |
> | 7 | 2 |
> | 8 | 2 |
> | 9 | 3 |
> | 10 | 3 |
> | 11 | 3 |
> | 12 | 3 |
> | 13 | 4 |
> | 14 | 4 |
> | 15 | 4 |
> | 16 | 4 |
> | 17 | 5 |
> | 18 | 5 |
> | 19 | 5 |
> | 20 | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=202961cdbc5d4e9c58e396e391fbe968)*